# Welcher Typ Konnektor ist "nach" im Sinne von "Nach Plan"?

Tags: grammar-identification

Wir können sagen "Dem Plan nach" aber auch "Nach Plan". Wahrscheinlich gleichbedeutend mit "entsprechend". Aber welcher Typ Konnektor ist diese Präposition hier?
Mein Verständnis wäre, dass es ein Restriktiver Konnektor ist, denn etwas, das nach Plan verläuft, verläuft nicht mehr beliebig, sondern ist begrenzt auf die Angaben des Plans. Genauso wie bei "Alle, außer Tom" Tom ausgeschlossen wird.
Im Duden finde ich das Beispiel aber nicht. Sie schreiben dort "Nach (Angabe von)", beziehungsweise "laut". Das nachgestellte "nach" finde ich bei den Konnektoren nicht erwähnt. Ich hoffe, dass das Beispiel nicht erwähnenswert war, denn meiner Ansicht nach ist die Bedeutung die gleiche. Trotzdem frage ich deshalb hier, um Bestätigung oder Belehrung zu bekommen.

Comment: Erwartest du jetzt eine lateinische Bezeichnung für die Semantik der Präposition "nach" im Sinne von "according to"? Inwiefern hilft denn das? Oder hast du irgendwo eine Klassifikation der Semantiken von Konnektoren gefunden, in die du das jetzt einordnen möchtest? Wo?

Comment: Ich suche einfach danach, zu welcher Gruppe der Konnektoren diese Verwendung von "nach" gehört. Die Gruppe, zu der ich dieses "nach" vermute, habe ich in meiner Frage bereits genannt. MfG

Comment: Du scheinst also irgendwo eine Liste der Konnektorengruppen gefunden zu haben, in die du jetzt die Präposition "nach" einordnen willst. Wo ist diese Liste? Ich finde "restriktiv" nicht falsch, aber auch nur begrenzt passend, denn es geht bei "nach" ja m.E. eher um das Nennen eines Kriteriums für eine Beurteilung als um das Auschließen anderer Möglichkeiten, deshalb die Rückfrage.

Comment: Welche Arten von Konnektoren gibt es? Gibt es dazu eine Übersicht?

Comment: Im Dudenband 4 findet sich eine Auflistung verschiedener Konnektoren. Ich kann nicht zum Dudenband 4 verlinken, da dieser kopiergeschützt ist und Geld kostet.

Comment: @OranMatheus, und warum listesten Sie sie in der Frage nicht einfach auf? Es werden ja nicht dutzende Konnektoren sein?

Answer (score 1):

Hier sind die Arten (Typen) von Konnektoren<sup>([1](https://www.deutschakademie.de/online-deutschkurs/deutschkurs/nach-thema/konjunktionaladverb-folglich-andernfalls-meinetwegen-nichtsdestotrotz))</sup>:

- kausale (Grund)
- konzessive (Gegengrund)
- adversative (Gegensatz)
- konsekutive (Folge)
- temporale (Zeit)

*Nach* ist in deinem Beispiel Synonym von *gemäß* oder *entsprechend*. Man kann sich nun streiten, ob der Plan für dessen Abarbeitung ein Grund ist oder die Abarbeitung eine Folge des Plans ist. Das kommt auf die Richtung der Sichtweise an. Ich würde bei ***nach*** zu konsekutiv tendieren, da es die Abarbeitung betrifft.